# Google Sheets Pie Chart - Can I replace percentages in legend with another value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-pie-chart

I would like to change the default percentages shown in a Google Sheets Pie Chart with the actual dollar values. Is that possible? I don't see anywhere to choose something other than the percentages. I know that I can remove them, but I want to replace them.

[image: Example Chart]

I have tried tweaking the various label fields, but I can't figure it out